# CSS 3 Columns Unordered List

Tags: html, css

One the [Portfolio of Sectors] tab on the following page there are 3 columns the second row of columns overlap, I am not sure how to get them all to line up, can anyone help me please?

http://berrisford.gumpshen.com

Comment: Please put the relevant HTML and CSS here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the list with class 'first' on the second row, should fix the issue.

You probably want to wrap each of these in a div as well.

Comment: unfortunatly it is generated in xslt and I can't wrap it in a div, would be so much earlier if I could

Answer (score 2):

`h4.second` and `h4.third` have a top margin of -30px.

See lines 926 and 934 of `style.css` respectively.

Comment: when I don't include that it messes up the first row

Comment: That's right, but it's the answer to your original question... ;-)

Comment: :) I would find that funny if there wasn't a deadline, cheers anyways

Comment: Sorry, it was a cheap snipe :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you change it to something like this? you'll find it easier once you have the markup sorted.

```
<div class="column3">
   <h4 class="third">Insurance</h4>
   <ul class="third">
     <li>
       <a href="/about-our-services/portfolio-of-industry-sectors/insurance/general-motor.aspx">General &amp; Motor</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```